# Slow Windows 8 Start Screen With Multiple Video Cards

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8

This probably sounds ridiculous, but I recently upgraded my 6-monitor setup to an 8-monitor one. The "primary" 6 monitors are running on an ASUS Radeon HD 7970. To add the additional two  "occasional use" monitors I added a cheaper Sapphire Radeon HD 6450. They're both running the  AMD Catalyst Win 8 Preview Drivers.

Dragging and dropping between screens went from buttery-smooth (60 fps+) to what I'm guessing must be around 30 fps. This is between screens on either the same video card or between cards (no difference). Launching the Windows 8 start screen is substantially slower (instead of instant it takes a few seconds with very choppy animation), even though it only appears on a single screen running on the 7970.

So I don't really understand why but I guess the 6450 is holding the 7970 back somehow - Windows is only running these animations as fast as the slowest card? Is that correct?

I can live with the slightly slower drag-and-drop but the start screen is very annoying. Can I expect this situation improve when updated drivers are released? Or do I have to just cough up the cash and buy another Radeon 7000 series to replace the 6450? The cheapest 7000s run around $200 so if I can find a better solution I'd rather not.

Comment: I've never seen problems like this in 7 with similar card combinations, and anyway even the 6450 is more than fast enough to render this stuff at full speed.  I'm guessing it's just a lousy driver.

Comment: Thanks. I've had some other issues with earlier versions of the Preview Drivers that have been fixed with updates. I'll wait a few months for the final drivers to come out :)

Comment: A good sanity test would be to pull the 7970 out entirely and see how it runs on just the one - I'm guessing better.  (I doubt the driver is so bad that the entire 6xxx series just runs at half speed in isolation.)

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest [driver from AMD/ATI](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx). Here's a direct link to the [32-bit](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_win8-32.aspx) and [64-bit](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_win8-64.aspx) driver pages for Windows 8.